# Creating interface in dart like typescript

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I am from typescript background and new to dart, in typescript we are able to define interface and attach those types to the required variable which have the correct format would work, for example

```
interface Answer {
  text: string;
  value: number;
}

interface Question {
  question: string;
  answers: Answer[
}


const questions: Question[] = [
    {
      'question': "What's your fav color?",
      'answers': [
        {
          'text': 'one',
          'value': 1,
        },
        {
          'text': 'one',
          'value': 2,
        },
        {
          'text': 'one',
          'value': 3,
        },
        {
          'text': 'one',
          'value': 4,
        },
      ],
    },
];
```

This would just do for typescript I will get no errors.

But in dart I am not able to achieve the same thing. Below is my dartpad code. please help me I am getting an error saying `The element type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the list type 'SingleQuestion'.`

Is there any resource which can help me overcome typescript to dart migration will be best for the suggestions.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=bcef24b3cbd94a2150454cf0edea3704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your data is json. Then use Object class for your data and fromJson function for SingleQuestion. Your main function like this:

```
void main() {
  Object data = {
      'question': "What's your fav color?",
      'answers': [
         {
           'text': 'red',
           'value': 1,
         },
         {
           'text': 'green',
           'value': 2,
         },
         {
           'text': 'yellow',
           'value': 3,
         },
         {
           'text': 'black',
           'value': 4,
         },
       ],
   };

  final List<SingleQuestion> questions = [SingleQuestion.fromJson(data)];

  print(questions[0].question);
  print(questions[0].answers[1].value);
  print(questions[0].answers[1].text);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer, I am getting a warning saying 
`The instance member 'data' can't be accessed in an initializer`, in intelIj. Also can you give me any advice on where can I learn these kind of things as I am new to dart and flutter.

Comment: Also I just saw you added an object, what if I need to add an array of objects

Comment: I fixed it by replacing the line to late final List<SingleQuestion> _questions = data.map((question) => SingleQuestion.fromJson(question)).toList(); is that okay?

Comment: Will mapping these things everytime will not hamper performance?

Comment: You should still answer the title if you can because that is whats linking people onto this thread.